# Axios does not catch error even not enter in catch block

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to get the error status code that would be 413 in Axios catch block. I have tried different solutions nothing worked for me. Could you please review what is going wrong.

```
uploadNewDatDocuments(datId, files = [], additionalInfo = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = new URL(this.baseUrl + this.uploadDocument.replace('{id}', datId));
        Object.keys(additionalInfo).forEach(queryParam => url.searchParams.set(queryParam, additionalInfo[queryParam]));
        let formData = new FormData();
        files.forEach(file => formData.append('files', file));
        axios
            .post(url.toString(), formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error occurred")
                reject(error);
            }).finally(error=>{
                console.log(error);
            })
    });
}
```

Here is my Action code.

```
export function uploadNewDocuments(datId, additionalInfo = {}, attachments = [], comment = {}) {
return dispatch => {
    datService
        .uploadNewDatDocuments(datId, attachments, additionalInfo)
        .then(response => {
            const attachmentsIds = response.map(attachment => attachment.id);
            dispatch(
                DatCommentActions.addDatNewComment(datId, {
                    ...comment,
                    message: { ...comment.message, attachments: attachmentsIds }
                })
            );
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(MessageActions.showMessage({ message: error.response.data.message }));
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

*413 Request Entity Too Large* is not actually error, its a not successful response and catch wont fire unless there is actual error on response.

What you could do is check response.status and based on that and write own *error* handling.

Comment: I cant event get 413 status code In .then.

Comment: and inside your network in your browser you get 413? @MehmoodZaman

Comment: yes, I am getting 413 in network tab.

Comment: can you show me outcome if you console.log response in then inside uploadNewDatDocuments and then in your dispatch function uploadNewDocuments then response?